# Can I call a function after the loading of an iframe appended by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/M9m8y/) :

```
​<div id="myContent​​​​​​​"></div>​

$('#myContent').html('<iframe height="200" frameborder="0" src="www.google.com"></iframe>');​
```

and I'd like, when the whole page in the frame is totally loaded, call a function, like `alert("I'm finished");`.

How can I do it?

P.S. dunno why jsfiddle doesnt catch the google page :)

Comment: JSFiddle needs http:// on the source URL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with the event [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) (Check the api for more info).

Example:

```
$('#myContent').html('<iframe id="winId" height="200" frameborder="0" src="www.google.com"></iframe>');

$('#winId').load(function() {alert('loaded')})
```

Comment: you should use the load and not ready ! there is a difference ! "load" is when completly loaded !

Comment: `ready` is used for the *current* page. It completely ignores the selector you pass in (if you don't believe me, have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L253)). `$('#winId').ready(function() {...})` is the same as `$().ready(function() {...})` or `$(function() {...})`. It won't attach an event handler to the iframe.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right. I did not notice that the selector is ignored. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, unless the iframe has the source url on the same domain/subdomain, checking if it has loaded completely, or expecting any kind of events to be propogated from a frame to the parent window is not possible.

The same domain policy clearly stops developers from doing such stuff.

Though there are a few workarounds ,e.g the code inside the iframe can change its url and keep passing information using hash tags and vice-a-versa.

Comment: In fact, the best strategy is to write on my page (the one called with iframe) $(window).load(function () { alert("ciao"); }); (yes, I have the control of the page :))

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myContent').html('<iframe height="200" frameborder="0" src="www.google.com" onload="myfunc()"></iframe>');
```

you should have in the page containing the IFRAME :

```
 function myfunc()
    {
       alert('.......');
    }
```

### edit  : the following will Not work.

```
 $('#myContent').on('load','#myIdframe',function (){alert('.....');});
```

since :

*From the documentation: In all browsers, the load event does not bubble. [...] Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event.*

heres 2 examples :

1 work and 1 doesn't

http://jsbin.com/emuzop/2/edit#javascript,html

http://jsbin.com/emuzop/3/edit#javascript,html

Comment: From the documentation: *In all browsers, the `load` event does not bubble. [...] Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event.*

Comment: `$("#facebookContent").on is not a function`, and I have jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: @FelixKling you right http://jsbin.com/emuzop/2/edit not seems to work while http://jsbin.com/emuzop/3/edit DOES.

Answer (score 1):

Create the element, then attach the load event:

```
var frame = $('<iframe height="200" frameborder="0" src=http://www.google.com />');

$('body').append(frame);
frame.load(function(){
    alert('loaded');
});
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x7EXa/