# Call child Javascript function from parent

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, iframe, parent-child

I have an iframe and inside that iframe a javascript function. I would like to be able to call that function from iframe's parent because I need to set some values inside the iframe when it opens. So far I tried:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "saveTasks", "<script type='text/javascript'> function SaveTasks() { frames['myIframe'].location.href = 'myURL'; frames['myIframe'].test(); } </script>");
```

However, I am not able to call the test() function found in myURL file.

What is the specific syntax to do this, to call a javascript function inside child from its parent? Thank you

Comment: Is this `iframe`'s URL in the same domain as your parent website?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same domain as the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not massively familiar with this.  It doesn't appear though that this segment of javascript has any way of being able to know what "frames['myIframe']" is.  There's a lot of things that could be potentially going wrong such as is the $document even loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this: it seems that my child page where the javascript function was found wasn't loaded at the moment when I was calling the function. Fortunately I found the solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466596/can-i-call-a-function-after-the-loading-of-an-iframe-appended-by-jquery).

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "saveTasks", "<script type='text/javascript'> function SaveTasks() { frames['ValidateTasksIframe'].location.href = 'myURL'; $('#ValidateTasksIframe').load(function() { frames['ValidateTasksIframe'].test();});} </script>");
```

Using event.load() works like a charm! :)